# cypher find relation direction

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I find a relation direction with regards to a containing path? I need this to do a weighted graph search that takes into account relation direction (weighing "wrong" direction with a `0`, see also comments).

Lets say:

```
START a=node({param})
MATCH a-[*]-b
WITH a, b
MATCH p = allshortestpaths(a-[*]-b)
RETURN extract(r in rels(p): flows_with_path(r)) as in_flow
```

where
`flows_with_path = 1` if `sp = (a)-[*0..]-[r]->[*0..]-(b)`, otherwise
`0`

EDIT: corrected query

Comment: What should happen if sp contains both, incoming and outgoing relationships?

Comment: in_flow would then point that out. E.g. [1, 0, 0, 1, 1] would mean there are 5 rels between a and b, and rel 0, 3, 4 are outgoing.It would also be possible that there is an incoming and an outgoing relation in a path that's otherwise the same. I guess it should say allshortestpaths to clarify this. In this case, e.g. with 2 relations in position 2 I might get 2 vectors, [1, 0, 0, 1, 1] and [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's a way to do it with existing cypher functions. I don't promise it's super performant, but give it a shot. We're building our collection with reduce, using an accumulator tuple with a collection and the last node we looked at, so we can check that it's connected to the next node. This requires 2.0's case/when syntax--there may be a way to do it in 1.9 but it's probably even more complex.

```
START a=node:node_auto_index(name="Trinity") 
MATCH a-[*]-b 
WHERE a <> b
WITH distinct a,b 
MATCH p = allshortestpaths(a-[*]-b) 
RETURN extract(x in nodes(p): x.name?), // a concise representation of the path we're checking
  head(
    reduce(acc=[[], head(nodes(p))], x IN tail(nodes(p)): // pop the first node off, traverse the tail
      CASE WHEN ALL (y IN tail(acc) WHERE y-->x)  // a bit of a hack because tail(acc)-->x doesn't parse right, so I had to wrap it so I can have a bare identifier in the pattern predicate
           THEN [head(acc) + 0, x]    // add a 0 to our accumulator collection
           ELSE [head(acc) + 1, x]    // add a 1 to our accumulator collection 
      END )) AS in_line
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/v0jx03

Output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| extract(x in nodes(p): x.name?)                               | in_line   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["Trinity","Morpheus"]                                        | [1]       |
| ["Trinity","Morpheus","Cypher"]                               | [1,0]     |
| ["Trinity","Morpheus","Cypher","Agent Smith"]                 | [1,0,0]   |
| ["Trinity","Morpheus","Cypher","Agent Smith","The Architect"] | [1,0,0,0] |
| ["Trinity","Neo"]                                             | [1]       |
| ["Trinity","Neo",<null>]                                      | [1,1]     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note: Thanks @boggle for the brainstorming session.

Comment: So the + in [head(acc) + 0, x] is appending elements to an array - equivalent to [head(acc) + [0], x], right?

Comment: I had to learn cypher to get this, but now I can confirm you maintain your status ;) But joking aside, I think it would be a great addition to the neo4j cypher docs if you just post a couple of your more advanced queries there. I learn a lot from each of them.